# iOS 7 Safari auto shrinking/hiding UI elements not working when scroll

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, scroll, ios7

When you scroll on a web page in iOS 7s Safari the URL bar shrinks and the bottom navigation bar disappears. In the site I am working on these two things to not happen.

The momentum/inertial scrolling was not working as well until I added -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; to the html element.

I can't imagine what element I have added to the code to have it lock up Mobile Safari like this.

*Hoping this isn't a repeat question, it's hard to know what to call this besides "shrinking/hiding".*

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally stumbled upon the solution last night in an article by Maximiliano Firtman's article [Breaking the Mobile Web](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review). The article points out many issues with the new Mobile Safari in iOS 7.

The solution to my problem was close to his answer (his being if there is overflow: scroll; on your page it will not trigger the auto UI hide feature) mine was an overflow: hidden; style.

Comment: With overflow: scroll, the navigation stays there but elements that are position: fixed don't stay that way. Instead, they start scrolling up or down with the page until scroll ends.